# C# Regular Expression to find characters between Space and |

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find characters that should come between space and |.

I am using the below expression but I could not get correct output.

```
@"\s\S*[|]\b"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this one :

```
(?<=\s)[^\|]*(?=\|)
```

Anubhava's answer is also correct, but in case of

```
String : "Helllo good day |on a go|there you are"
Match :  "good day ", "a go", "you are"           // Anubhava's
Match :  "good day ", "a go"                      // this one

// "you are" should not be matched as not in between space and |. | is not there at the end
```

this regex has three parts:

- `(?<=\s)` : look-back for one space
- `[^\|]*` : anything other than |
- `(?=\|)` : look-ahead for |

so, together `(?<=\s)[^\|]*(?=\|)` will match the sequence which has a **`space( )`** before it, and a **`|`** after, without including them in the match.

You can [test the regex here](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Comment: One more help Denim.Between space and |, it should match the character count should be only 3..

Comment: @user518363 : sorry, didn't get you. can you please elaborate.

Comment: @user518363 : ok, in case of string : **"xyxy abc| def| mnmn|"**, should it match only "abc" and "def"? in that case change **`(?<=\s)[^\|]*(?=\|)`** to **`(?<=\s)[^\|]{3}(?=\|)`**.

Comment: @user518363 : one more thing, should it match word-characters only, or any character, including digits, special chars and spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
"(?<=\s)[^|]*"
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. please consider marking it as "accepted" if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
/\ ([^ \|]*)\|/
```

You can test this regular expression on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)